# XADC Current Sensing Reference Design

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, adc, instrumentation-amplifier, current-sensing

Please refer to this [reference design for AC701](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/boards_and_kits/artix-7/ac701-schematic-xtp218-rev1-0.pdf) (snippet below).

The schematics, specifically the current sensing sections in pages 34-36, show this:

[image: snippet from AC701 reference schematics]

I want to understand why, for the REF output of [INA333](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina333.pdf), there is a pull-up of 0.05V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to understand why, for the REF output of INA333, there is a
>   pull-up of 0.05V?

The minimum voltage that the INA333 can produce when the negative power rail is attached to 0 volts is typically 50 mV so, if the REF pin were tied directly to ground, the output would not change for inputs that might otherwise have caused a 50 mV rise in the output.

By attaching REF to 50.7 mV, it means you get linearity from the "null" input condition upwards. The price you pay is that you have a 50 mV offset but, given that your circuit implies that a differential ADC is used, this is of no-consequence.

Comment: Thanks for your input Andy,  Adding to the question, why there is R457 used in the path ?

Comment: R457 and C187 act as a low pass filter on the "P" line to the ADC. The "N" line is also filtered by the parallel impedance of R35/R36 acting with C505 so the filtering is consistent on N and P ADC inputs. However, if you do the math, R457 should be a tad under 100 ohm for perfect balanced low pass (possible anti-alias) filtering.